# have to get data from VISIT_Table filter with only date no time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT * 
FROM VISIT_Table 
WHERE 
    ID='" + ID + "' AND 
    DATE ='" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + @"'";
```

Above is my query I have to get data from `VISIT_Table` filter with only date no datetime..

In database `visit_date` stores `2012-10-27 11:10:35` I have to get data with only date no time

Comment: Conversion is expensive, which may be an issue for you if you're doing this alot.  Refer here for some other approaches that may be appropriate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275737/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-fields-in-sql-2005

Comment: First of all: **STOP** concatenating together your SQL queries! That's bad for security - you're wide open for SQL injection attacks - and it's really bad for performance, too! Use **parametrized queries** instead - **ALWAYS**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Visit_Date, 120) AS [Date],ID FROM PATIENT_VISIT
```